# Gridview elements not getting centered in relativeLayout

Tags: android, gridview

I am using a gridview in my application in which I want to make my view centered if there only one element in my adapter and maximum of three elements in one row.But for some reason one element is not being centered.
Please help me in this.

this is my parent layout

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
     >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/cplist_title_layout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="74dp"
        android:gravity="center_vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/cplist_title"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="74dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="32dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="32dp"
            android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
            android:textColor="@color/RGB_0_176_241"
            android:textSize="19dp" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/cplist_grid_layout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/cplist_title_layout"
        android:paddingTop="8dp" >

        <GridView
            android:id="@+id/cp_gridView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="21dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="32dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="32dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:numColumns="auto_fit"
            android:verticalSpacing="0dp"
            android:horizontalSpacing="0dp"
             >
        </GridView>
    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

this is my grid view item layout

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/detail_cplist_item_logo"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="108dp"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/detail_cplist_item_cplogo_bg"
        android:layout_width="225dp"
        android:layout_height="104dp"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:background="@color/RGB_23_27_33"
        android:gravity="center" />


</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/detail_cplist_item_details"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="59dp"
    android:layout_below="@id/detail_cplist_item_logo"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/detail_cplist_item_price"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="31dp"
         >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/detail_cp_price_text"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="6dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:text="Free"
            android:textColor="@color/RGB_100_217_217_217"
            android:textSize="18dp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/detail_cplist_item_quality_section"
        android:layout_width="37dp"
        android:layout_height="19dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/detail_cplist_item_price"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="9dp"
         >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/detail_cplist_item_quality"
            android:layout_width="37dp"
            android:layout_height="19dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:src="@drawable/common_selector_icon_hd" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/detail_cplist_item_tag_tv"
        android:layout_width="21dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/detail_cplist_item_price"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="9dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/detail_cplist_item_quality_section"
        android:src="@drawable/tag_tv"
        android:visibility="invisible" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/detail_cplist_item_tag_mobile"
        android:layout_width="21dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/detail_cplist_item_price"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/detail_cplist_item_tag_tv"
        android:src="@drawable/tag_mobile" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/detail_cplist_item_live_icon"
        android:layout_width="37dp"
        android:layout_height="19dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/detail_cplist_item_price"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/detail_cplist_item_quality_section"
        android:src="@drawable/tag_live"
        android:visibility="invisible" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: how do you add elements to the grid view?

Comment: which element is not being centered??

Comment: I edited my question along with my item layout which i inflate in getView

Comment: i add elements through arrayadapter

Answer (score 0):

Instead of gravity, set this:

```
android:layout_centerInParent="true"
```

Comment: You can either remove the LinearLayout and put that on the TextView, or put that on the LinearLayout.  It doesn't work on a widget not directly inside the RelativeLayout.

Comment: actually i want to move my gridview elements to the center_horizontal and not the Textview

Comment: even centeInParent for linearlayout doesnt work.Still my gridview items are in left side

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem... I solved it with overridden onMeasure()

```
public class GridViewEx extends GridView {

    private int mRequestedNumColumns = 0;

    public GridViewEx(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public GridViewEx(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public GridViewEx(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    @Override
    public void setNumColumns(int numColumns) {
        super.setNumColumns(numColumns);

        if (numColumns != mRequestedNumColumns) {
            mRequestedNumColumns = numColumns;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);

        if (mRequestedNumColumns > 0) {
            int width = (mRequestedNumColumns * getColumnWidth())
                    + ((mRequestedNumColumns-1) * getHorizontalSpacing())
                    + getListPaddingLeft() + getListPaddingRight();

            setMeasuredDimension(width, getMeasuredHeight());    
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was using

```xml
android:layout_below="@+id/msg"
```

works fine after i removed it and used

```xml
android:layout_centerInParent="true"
```